# How to use IObjectClassEvents?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, esri-geodatabase, events

I need to use IObjectClassEvents in my project. I don't know how to start, can any one give me a simple explanation, or an example in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple helpful links to get you started:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeodatabase/IObjectClassEvents_Example.htm

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000610000000

VB code may be converting using [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) site.